# Why is it that for Indian Muslims in rural areas, wealth and upward social mobility are not associated with greater female seclusion?

Tags: india, religion, gender

India has one of the lowest female labour participation rates in the world [(ref)](https://www.reuters.com/world/india/indias-female-labour-participation-rate-falls-161-pandemic-hits-jobs-2021-08-03/#:%7E:text=According%20to%20World%20Bank%20estimates,actively%20looking%20for%20a%20job.), [this twitter thread](https://twitter.com/_alice_evans/status/1460266752231759879?t=NgTWnmV2o_VrsHLaGJvzAw&s=19) says that as Indian families become wealthier, they tighten female mobility to buy respectability in rural areas (backed by some papers). My interest is in this remark:

> But among Indian Muslims, wealth and upward mobility are NOT associated with greater female seclusion.

Does there exist theoretical explanation/narrative on why Indian Muslims don't follow the general trend?

Comment: The difference might be smaller than you think: just because for non-muslim Indians there is an association detectable, doesn't mean it's big. Maybe it's also very weak and for Muslims it might even be there, just not detectable in the data. I would also look at the strength of the correlations before asking for explanations.

Comment: A key detail that the tweet emphasizes but the question ignores is that the correlation between wealth and female seclusion exists in *only in rural areas*. [Muslims are somewhat more likely to live in towns and cities than Hindus](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/india/more-religious-minorities-live-in-urban-areas-than-rural/articleshow/48680765.cms). So you may want to look at the numbers to see if religion really is the most relevant variable.